# Zip Extractor for Mac

Tags: macos, zip

Does anyone have a recommendation for a free zip extractor for Mac? I've tried Zipeg but it doesn't seem to be supported by Catalina at present. The others I've looked at seem a little sketchy.

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in Archiver? By default you just double-click to unzip.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Keka](https://www.keka.io/en/).

From the web site:

> Keka can create files in these formats:
> 7Z ZIP TAR GZIP BZIP2 XZ LZIP DMG ISO
>
> And extract all of these formats:
> 7Z ZIP ZIPX RAR TAR GZIP BZIP2 XZ LZIP DMG ISO LZMA EXE CAB WIM PAX JAR WAR IPA APK APPX >XPI CPGZ CPIO

Answer (score 0):

WinZip for MAC comes in 64-bit (needed for Catalina). I use WinZip myself.